# Laravel - How to get data from two models?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I would like to get all the data from the relationship by menu id in this case. How can i do that?

I have tried search online but could not find a similar case... Please help...

Here are my models:

#### Menu

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'img', 'status', 'views'
    ];

    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class, 'store_menu');
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }

}
```

#### Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["img", "title", "description", "status", "menu_id"];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }

    public function menu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Menu::class, 'menu_id');

    }
}
```

#### Item

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'img', 'price', 'status', 'view', 'category_id'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

By doing the following i only manage to get the menu's categories:

```
$id = $request->menu_id;
$menu = Menu::find($id);
$categories = $menu->categories;
dd(menu);
```

#### Current result:

```
"data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Menu name",
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Category 1 name",
                "menu_id": 1,
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Category 1 name",
                "menu_id": 1,
                
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Category 1 name",         
                "menu_id": 1,
            }
        ]
    },
```

#### Result i would like to get:

```
"data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Menu Name",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Category 1 name",
                "menu_id": 1,
                "items":[
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Item 1 Name"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Item 2 Name"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Category 2 name",
                "menu_id": 1,
                "items":[
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Item 3 Name"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Item 4 Name"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Category 3 name",
                "menu_id": 1,
                "items":[
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Item 5 Name"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Item 6 Name"
                    },
                ]

            }
        ]
    },
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can utilize eager loading to load nested relationships:

```
$menu = Menu::with('categories.items')->find($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

u can do this

```
$id = $request->menu_id;
$menu = Menu::find($id);
$menu->categories = $menu->categories;
dd(menu);
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$id = $request->menu_id;
$menu = Menu::with('categories')->find($id);
dd(menu);
```